# How to redirect to another page using the url alias?

Tags: 8, forms, redirection

Here is my code where I am trying to redirect to a page using its url alias:

```
    $url= Url::fromUserInput('/thank_you_for_your_message')->toString();
    $form_state->setRedirect($url); 
    return;
```

and I get this error : `Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\RouteNotFoundException: Route "/thank_you_for_your_message" does not exist. in Drupal\Core\Routing\RouteProvider->getRouteByName()`

Is the fromUserInput the correct way to redirect to an internal url alias?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here you can see an example that works for me:

I use `'internal:url-alias'`

```
use \Drupal\Core\Url;
...

$search_page = '/en/faith-community/find-a-parish';
$form_state->setRedirectUrl(Url::fromUri('internal:' . $search_page));
```

Answer (score 1):

to ensure that the internal alias exists, check for the route before trying to redirect

```php
$search_page = Url::fromUri ('internal:/en/faith-community/find-a-parish');

if ($search_page->isRouted()) {
  $form_state->setRedirectUrl($search_page);
}
```

Comment: How is `$search_page->getInternalPath()` supposed to work if it's a string?

Comment: @TerranRich I have absolutely no clue what I was thinking  ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: It happens to the best of us!